# Autolayout uitextfield content vertical alignment center

Tags: iphone, ios7, uitextfield, xcode5, vertical-alignment

I am using autolayout, I have put constraints on textfield such as same width, same height bottom alignment left and right align to certain controls. My problem is that I am not able to do content vertically alignment center. I tried both from xib and coding but it is not working and comes aligned to top. I am using xcode5. These problem occurs in any ios(I am basically developing from ios6 to ios 7). Please help.